# Where is the link to the Server Fault Blog?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Since we now have a full-time staff member that can write blog entries, should a link to the blog be provided?

Right now, the only link is in the Server Fault footer.  Don't users of SO want to see the SF blog?  Or, don't SF users want to see the SO blog?

Comment: I thought Google was supposed to be the SF navigation tool.  If you search for [serverfault blog](http://www.google.com/search?q=serverfault+blog) the link is pretty close to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the same place as the link to the Stack Overflow blog -- in the footer!

So it's symmetric, in that sense -- on SO, the blog goes to blog.so ; on SF, the blog link goes to blog.sf.

Comment: and on meta, the blog goes to blog.meta.stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

So you can't miss it:

↓    Click here[!](http://blog.serverfault.com)   ↓
Click here[!](http://blog.serverfault.com) → [blog.serverfault.com](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Server-Fault/89088433691?v=wall)   ← Click here[!](http://blog.serverfault.com)
                          ↑    Click here[!](http://blog.serverfault.com)   ↑

Comment: Ahahahahahaha!!

Comment: Why does this link to facebook?

Comment: @Justin: I do not explain my jokes.

Comment: I think it has to be funny to be a joke... `:P`